# Geoserver pyramid DEM goes to 0 at a certain zoom level

Tags: gis, gdal, geoserver, webworldwind

I'm trying to make a pyramid to serve my own digital elevation model from geoserver to webworldwind by using geoserver's ImagePyramid plugin and the DDS/BIL extension.

As source files, I used a bunch of geotiffs from "ALOS World 3D - 30m (AW3D30)" and retiled them with this command:

```
gdal_retile.py -v -levels 12 -ps 8192 8192 -targetDir "$TARGET_DIR" "${SOURCE_DIR}"/*.tif
```

Everything seems to work OK until I reach a certain zoom level, at which the elevation data goes to 0.

Comment: what does the log file say? turn debug up to devel if nothing obvious shows up